# Why does piping the output of $RANDOM affect the value?

Tags: bash, random

Below is a script that I expect to generate the same pair of numbers three times:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
RANDOM=5
echo " first" $RANDOM
echo "second" $RANDOM

echo

RANDOM=5
echo " first" $RANDOM
echo "second" $RANDOM

echo

RANDOM=5
echo "??????" $RANDOM | cat
echo " first" $RANDOM
```

Instead, piping the output prevents the random seed from being respected.  Why?

```
 first 18499
second 9909

 first 18499
second 9909

?????? 843
 first 18499
```

---

Ultimately, I'd like to be able do something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
n=3
for i in $( seq $n) ; do
    RANDOM=5
    echo $RANDOM | md5sum | cut -d' ' -f1
done
```

What modifications can I make to the latter script so that its output is the same each time I run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since @JohnKugelman's answer isn't working for me, here's an alternative (that also has the advantage that it'll work in non-bash shells that don't support `<<<`). Just assign a temp variable to the result from `$RANDOM`, and then use the temp variable in the subshell (or other weird context):

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
RANDOM=5
echo " first" $RANDOM
echo "second" $RANDOM

echo

RANDOM=5
tmprandom=$RANDOM
echo " first" $tmprandom | cat
echo "second" $RANDOM
```

Output (under bash v4; v3 uses a different random number generator):

```
 first 18499
second 9909

 first 18499
second 9909
```

Answer (score 3):

The commands in a pipeline are executed in subshells, and subshells have their own independent environment variables. `$RANDOM` is updated in the pipeline and this update doesn't propagate to the parent shell, which is why you see `18499` from the following `echo`.

In this case you can avoid a pipeline by using `<<<` redirection instead. Redirection does not create a child process.

```
cat <<< "?????? $RANDOM"
```

or

```
(md5sum | cut -d' ' -f1) <<< "$RANDOM"
```

Comment: @zee That won't work, since `<( )` *does* create a subshell. @JohnKugelman I don't understand why, but yours isn't working for me either (it acts like the `<<<` string is being evaluated in a subshell, even though it clearly shouldn't be). I've tested in bash v4.4.19, 4.2.10, and v3.2.57.

Comment: I tried [many bash versions](https://gist.github.com/MatrixManAtYrService/2903762631599b2b7673c2cc1406140f) and this answer only worked for 3.1, and 3.2.57

Comment: Why the output is repeatable if it's supposed to be random? what's the meaning of the seed?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz `$RANDOM` bases its output on the previous value of `$RANDOM` so if you let your shell initialize it, it will be difficult to predict.  If you set it yourself at some point, it will then behave the same each time afterwards (unless you call into a new shell, which creates a new unpredictable one for that shell).  It's still not a very good source of randomness because once you know its value at one time, you can predict its values at subsequent times.  If you need real randomness /dev/urandom is a better way to go.

Comment: Redirection does not create a subshell. But here-docs (and here-strings) do. Or they might, at least. How would you implement here-docs? You could write the text from the here-doc to a temporary file, and redirect stdin to the temporary file. Or you could fork the bash process and redirect stdin to a pipe into which the child is writing the here-doc. Posix doesn't specify the mechanism (and the bash manual doesn't document it, afaik) but it's easy to see the temptation to use the second one. Contrast `i=0; echo $((++i)); echo $i` with `i=0; cat<<<$((++i)); echo $i`